# Apply holidays and weekends when adding days to date

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here's my data:

[image]

C2=A2+B2, but I want to apply the `Off Dates` column to that, so the real `End Date` should be 3/25/2021 because 21, 22, 23 and 24 are not work days.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `WORKDAY(start_date,duration,[list_of_holidays])` for example `=WORKDAY(B2,C2,I2:I5)` this will give you the serial number of the date convert it to date format or use `=TEXT(WORKDAY(B2,C2,I2:I5),"dd-mm-yy")`

Comment: In my case I should use ```workday.intl``` because the weekends are different in my region. But thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of this function at all.